# image not showing

Tags: image, facebook-sharer

I use this to show image and title, but since a few weeks it's not working any more.  I can't find why.  I read the developer site again, but [nothing changed](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://resepgulaku.com/resepdetail.aspx?id=15&t=3839926976%20href=&src=sp).

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, the [debug tool output for your page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fresepgulaku.com%2Fresepdetail.aspx%3Fid%3D15%26t%3D3839926976) shows you're missing the necessary meta tags but Facebook's made a guess at the title, etc and it seems OK to me.

When i share that URL the title and description load fine. The only image URL Facebook detected is a 404 error so maybe that's what your problem is, was it displaying OK on Facebook before you removed the image?

Comment: no image for this one, I checked everything again, and yes you're right, it works:

Comment: no image for this one, I checked everything again, and yes you're right, it works:{link]https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.resepgulaku.com%2FIndex2v2_recipedetail.aspx%3Fid%3D62%26t%3D3839926976[\link]